# How to count occurrences of a path in an array of objects with ramda.js?

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I'm trying to use `ramda.js` to count occurrences of a key-value pair inside an array of objects, such as:

```
var array = [
  {a: {b: 'a'}},
  {a: {b: 'a'}},
  {a: {b: 'X'}},
  {a: 'a'}
]
```

If I wanted to count the number of times `{a: {b: 'a'}}` occurs inside of `array` in `ramda.js`, what would I do?

Comment: Think in terms of these steps:
[1] `R.pathEq` to check whether an array element matches
[2] `R.map` to check every element of the array, converting it to `true` or `false`
[3] `Number` can be used as a function to convert from `true` to `1` and `false` to `0`
[4] `R.sum` to tally up all the `1`s in the array

Let me know if you need more assistance than the above and I can provide a complete solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may hate it, pointfree function.

```
R.compose(R.length, R.filter(R.compose( R.equals('a'), R.path(['a', 'b']))))(array)
```

**UPDATE** Just learned from comment of Scott Christopher.

R.compose(R.equals(val), R.Path(p1, p2)) == R.pathEq([p1, p2], val)

function can be shorten to

```
R.compose(R.length, R.filter(R.pathEq(['a', 'b'], 'a')))(array)
```

Comment: Thank you, I think it's a good way as it's very concise :-)
https://jsfiddle.net/8s9ae61L/